# How can a lazy loaded module inherit App Modules Declarations?

Tags: angular

I have a lazy loaded module that needs to use a component. I have added it to app modules declarations and expect that this should make the declared **component** app wide.

Although Angular can't recognize the component in the lazy loaded **module**. I tried adding it to both module declarations then and got a warning asking to add the declaration in a higher module above the `app.module` and `lazyLoaded.module`.

e.g. (`nameOfModule/Component`)

> Error: Type (DeclareMeComponent) is part of the declarations of 2 modules: (AppModule) and (LazyLoadedModule)! Please consider moving (DeclareMeComponent) to a higher module that imports AppModule and (LazyLoadedModule). You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes (DeclareMeComponent) then import that NgModule in (AppModule) and (DeclareMeComponent).

What is ***higher*** than `app.module`? and how can I get the lazy loaded module to **inherit**/**use** the declared component along with **app** module?

Comment: You create a Shared Module as the last sentence implies. https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#shared-modules

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Higher than `AppModule` would be a `SharedModule`. Here you can define components which you will use in your `AppModule` and inside any lazy loaded modules.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    DeclareMeComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    DeclareMeComponent,
    CommonModule
  ]    
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

Here you will declare and export components, directives, pipes, the whole shebang. Core building blocks which you will use throughout your entire application. Here you will probably also import and export the `CommonModule`. It's like the `BrowserModule`, but then something you can import more than once inside an application.

You can now use your shared component inside your `AppModule` and any other module by importing it.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    SharedModule
  ]   
})
export class AppModule {}
```

As you can see, there is no need to declare `DeclareMeComponent` inside the `AppModule`, because it's imported from the higher `SharedModule`

Comment: Thanks for this! : )

Comment: I am also coming across this kind of issue in my angular project.  " undefined is not a function
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at webpackAsyncContext (eval at ./src/$$_lazy_route_resource lazy recursive (main.bundle.js:13), <anonymous>:100:34)
    at SystemJsNgModuleLoader.loadFactory (core.js:6590)
    at SystemJsNgModuleLoader.load (core.js:6554)
    at RouterConfigLoader.loadModuleFactory (router.js:4595)
    at RouterConfigLoader.load (router.js:4575)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.eval [as project] (router.js:2061)".